# how can the syntactic analyzer ignore white space in the input

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

In the code down below, although I added `\t` as a token, with a priority higher than the digits, still when I test it, it accepts `-2- 2` (with a single whitespace after the `-`)  and `-2 - 2` (with 2 whitespaces surrounding the `-`) but it does not accept `-2-2` (with no whitespaces). Is there a solution for this particular situation?

What I'm aiming for is that when i give it an input such as `-2-2-2` or `2*3/6-1` it works fine and does not output 'syntax error'.

`lexical.l`

```c
/* recognize tokens for the calculator and print them out */
/*"--"[0-9]+ { yytext++; yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }*/
%{
#include"syntax.tab.h"

%}

%%
"+"    { return ADD; }
"-"    { return SUB; }
"*"    { return MUL; }
"/"    { return DIV; }
"|"    { return ABS; }
[ \t]  { /* ignore whitespace */ }
(-|"")[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n     { return EOL; }

.      { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

`syntax.y`

```c
/* simplest version of calculator */
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token EOL

%%

calclist: /* nothing */                       
 | calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n", $2); }
 ;

exp: factor       
 | exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 ;

factor: term        
 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;

term: NUMBER   
 | ABS term   { if ($2 < 0) $$ = -$2; else $$ = $2; }
;
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yyparse();
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}`
```

Comment: How do you add two negative numbers ? -2 ADD -2 ? ie. -2 + -2. In reality, there is no such thing as subtraction. Add -- to your list as ADD then remove SUB. The default is ADD between operators.

Comment: You didn't add whitespace as a token. It isn't a token. You added a lex rule that ignores it. This is correct. However your optional leading minus rule is wrong. Leading minus *should* be handled as a token, in the grammar, not as part of the numeric literal.

Comment: @sln, but then how would ADD treat two cases? the addition and substraction. I'm sorry I'm new to such cases, can you explain more?

Comment: @sln This is just bad advice. Crippling the grammar just so it is slightly easier to code it?

Comment: @sln Your suggestion is complete nonsense. Compilers don’t do this.

Answer (score 2):

`-2-2` is interpreted by the lexer as `-2` `-2`, not as `-2` `-` `2`.
Lexer always looks for the longest match so it will always prefer to treat a minus and a number as a single token.

Your parser doesn't have a rule that accept two consecutive numbers so it shows an error.
(You should learn to turn on debug output in the lexer and the parser. It is very helpful in such cases.)

To fix the problem, you need to remove `-` as part of a number in the lexer.
Having it baked into a number is very common mistake that leads to exactly such problems as you encountered.
Instead, you can define unary `-` operator in the parser.

(Btw., `(-|"")` can be written as `-?`.)